# How to call native activity from java activity?

Tags: java, android, native-activity

I know we can call an activity from another android activity as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794120/call-other-activities-in-an-activity) question. My question is can we call a native activity from android activity through an intent or by using any other way? If yes, how?

`Android.mk` file of my native activity is following and native activity code is building fine

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mynativeactivity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

I am using this piece of xml to include my native activity in `AndroidManifest.Xml` file. And I think I am making a mistake here.

```
 //...rest of the xml including my main java activity here
  <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity" android:label="mynativeactivity" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.mynativeactivity"                  android:value="native-activity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I fix XML above so that in my first java based activity I can do something like this (if it is possible)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, mynativeactivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Currently I can't compile this code because compiler cannot locate `mynativeactivity`

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need this, but just in case someone else stumbles on this

You need to change `mynativeactivity.class` to `NativeActivity.class`
Also, make sure `android_main` calls `app_dummy()`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your XML should look something like:

```
  <activity android:name="YourJavaActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity     android:name="android.app.NativeActivity">
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="YourNativeLibraryName" />
    </activity>
```

And replace 'YourJavaActivity' with the name of your Java activity, and 'YourNativeLibraryName' with the name of your library that gets created (without the 'lib' prefix).

If you derive from NativeActivity then you also need to change android.app.NativeActivity to the name of your derived class.

Then you can start your native activity as desired.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNativeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```